# Android LVL: Could not bind to service

Tags: android, android-lvl

I'm trying to run LVL on my app but I'm getting this error when debugging on my phone:

**ERROR/LicenseChecker(29924): Could not bind to service.**

I tried on emulator too and I'm getting the same error, so I decided investigate on LicenseChecker.java and I changed:

```
               boolean bindResult = mContext.bindService(
                    new Intent(ILicensingService.class.getName()),
                    this,  // ServiceConnection.
                    Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

to:

```
                boolean bindResult = mContext.bindService(
                    new Intent("com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService"),
                    this,  // ServiceConnection.
                    Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

but same problem occurs.

I'm testing with SDK 8, any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for the hint with `new Intent("com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService")` :)

Comment: I just wanted to add on to what Martin said, that line is especially important if you refactor the licensing library.